# Auto submitting HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, forms, submit

I have a Javascript function which gets two variables. I have then got the JS to generate a line of HTML, this being a form filled with these two variables. Ive set the method to post to the server, and the form is hidden. I was wondering how do I get this to auto submit as I really don't want to use a submit button.

```
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    document.geo.submit()
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
  x.innerHTML=
  "<form action='' name='geo' method='post'> Longitude: <input type='int' name='longitude' value='"+ position.coords.longitude +"'> Latitude: <input type='int' name='latitude' value='"+ position.coords.latitude +"'> </form>  ";
}
```

Many thanks 
-Joe

Comment: please post some code of what you have done

Comment: Have you tried <body onload="submitform()">

Comment: Okay here is my js funcction, dynamically creating an html form

Answer (score 0):

Build the form with DOM instead of inner HTML. Then append it to the document and call its `submit` method.

```
var form = document.createElement('form');
    form.action = location;
    form.method = 'POST';
var long = document.createElement('input');
    long.name = "longitude";
    long.value = position.coords.longitude;
var lat = document.createElement('input');
    lat.name = "latitude";
    lat.value = position.coords.latitude;
form.appendChild(long);
form.appendChild(lat);
x.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
```

Comment: Would give rep, but haven't got enough too!